# Mathematical Definition of a n-dimensional convex body

Tags: convex-geometry, centroid, convex-hulls

Let $B$ be a convex body represented by a convex set $C$.
$C$ may contain infinite points $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

How can you define the centroid of $B$ based on $C$ or based by $B$'s(or $C$'s) convexity?

Please advise and thanks in advance.

Comment: What vectors space is this in?  Sounds like it is all in ${\bf R}$, in which case the convex body is a segment, and the centroid is the midpoint.  If not, please clarify.

Convexity makes sense in any vector space.  However, to define "centroid", one needs some kinds of a measure defined on that vector space.  Once we have a measured vector space, the centroid is just the integral of $f(x) = x$ over $C$ with respect to that measure.

Comment: I have changed it, thnx for that.
moreover, what kind of measures are you talking about?

Comment: Since we are in ${\bf R}^{n}$, there is always the Lebesgue measure.  However, any Borel measure will do, and the definition of the centroid will depend on the specific choice of measure.

Comment: What does it mean to say that $B$ is "represented by" $C$?

Comment: "all the points" in B are also in C